# Submit array in http flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart

This is how I post the two values to server using postman.

[image]

How should I write in http?

```
   var url = "xxx";
    var response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: {
        ....  
      'all_receivers': adminList.toString(),
      'commence_time': endTime, // this no issue
        ...
    });
```

I pass `adminList` which is `[725,607]`, but get error:

**Error**

```
all_receivers id [725 is invalid. all_receivers id  607] is invalid.
```

Comment: What happens if you write `response.fields['all_receivers'] = adminList`

Comment: Why not convert your list to a string and parse it when you receive it ?

Comment: @MidhunMP server will return `all_receivers id [725 is invalid. all_receivers id  783] is invalid. `

Comment: @D.Lucas i want post to server.

Comment: your question isn't clear, remove toString from the array, encode the map to json, assuming the content type is json

Comment: Content-type header expected by the service? and is the same Content-type posted by the client?

Comment: @Yadu Yes. And `all_receivers` is key.

Comment: try the answer posted by @Abhishek Ghaskata, you have to encode the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed

```
final receivers = adminList.join(",");
final body = {'all_receivers':receivers}
http.post(url', body: body);
```

Comment: This is not a convenient way because you are converting your list to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You create a json and pass it
or
You can create and array of strings

You can simply resolve that by casting your List to String.

By casting the token list using toString() method you will get a String like this `"['token1','token2']"`

Here's the modified code:

```
List<String> adminList=["725","607"]; // how to pass 725,607

var response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: {
       'all_receivers': adminList.toString(), // how to pass 725,607
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to pass with jsonEncode

```
 var response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: JsonEncode({
       'all_receivers': adminList, 
   });
 print(response);
```

Comment: I have fixed using `.join`.